# How to make Adyen SDK work on IE and Edge

Tags: html, sdk, adyen

I'm setting up online payments using the Adyen SDK 1.9.4.
It works fine on Chrome, Safari, Opera and Firefox but throws a Javascript error on IE and Edge.

SCRIPT5009: 'chckt' is not defined

'chckt' should be an object that is initialised when the Adyen SDK javascript library is loaded.

I've tried stripping the code back to a simple html page and it still errors.
I've also tried contacting Adyen support but after dozens of emails, I'm no closer to solving the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="html">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Test checkout</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/assets/js/sdk/checkoutSDK.1.9.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Test</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        test_chckt();
    });

    function test_chckt()
    {
        console.log('chckt is: ' + typeof chckt);
        console.log(chckt);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The code should output:
chckt is: object
Object

But in IE and Edge the output is:
chckt is: undefined
SCRIPT5009: 'chckt' is not defined

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the  `$(document).ready()`. You can simply say `console.log(chckt)` and it works. Maybe the cb has a different scope and it can't find it. If you really want you can try `window.chckt`.

Comment: I've tried without jQuery and I still get the same error